# How to place paper cutting line in middle of every page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, draw, everypage

How to put paper cutting line in the middle of every pages. Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bbding,lipsum}
\begin{document}   
  \lipsum{1-10}
  \noindent \raisebox{-1.0ex}{\ScissorHollowRight} \hfill \tikz \draw [dashed] (-12,0) -- (7,0);\rotatebox{180}{\raisebox{-1ex}{\ScissorHollowRight}}
  \lipsum{1-10}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node at (current page.center) {Your text here};`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Package [`eso-pic`](https://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) can be used to put something on *every* page:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bbding,lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic,picture}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \put(0,.5\paperheight){\makebox(0,0)[cl]{\ScissorHollowRight}}%
    \put(1.5em,.5\paperheight){\tikz\draw[dashed] (0,0) --
      (\paperwidth-3em,0);}
    \put(\dimexpr\paperwidth-1.5em\relax,0.5\paperheight){\makebox(0,0)[cl]{\reflectbox{\ScissorHollowRight}}}
  }%
}
\begin{document}   
  \lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image: two pages of the output]

or with a single `\tikz` instead of three `\put`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bbding,lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic,picture}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \put(0,.5\paperheight){\tikz\draw[dashed] (0,0) node
      {\ScissorHollowRight} -- (\paperwidth-1.5em,0) node {
        \reflectbox{\ScissorHollowRight} };
      }
  }%
}
\begin{document}   
  \lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```